# Div box styling

Tags: html, css

I been playing with `css` around a div for sometime now, and still couldn't find a way to copy the picture below.
[image]

Anyone can help would be great. And it should be a `div` or something that I can put a text inside.

Comment: Can you post what youve done so far?

Comment: i did only a box, coz been thinking how to do the arrow thingy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [CssArrowPlease](http://cssarrowplease.com/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A bit tricky, but doable with pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<span class="hover-me">Mouse goes here</span>
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-origin-border">
        <div class="tooltip-origin-inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip-content">
        This is a tooltip.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    display: none;
}
.tooltip-content {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #33c;
    background: #ddf;
}
.tooltip-origin-border {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #33c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -19px;
    position: absolute;
}

.tooltip-origin-inner {
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #ddf;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    position: absolute;
}
.hover-me {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hover-me:hover + .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

You just need to play with the positions. The "arrow" is actually a box, with transparent left, top and bottom borders, leaving only the right one visible and because of the way they connect to each other, there's a triangle shape. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h55tS/)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately speed and automation beat me :)

Comment: Sorry mate, if i were OP i would choose your answer :(

Comment: yup this awesome, will be bookmarking this :) and sorry i got what i need when Veil posted his answer .

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->http://jsfiddle.net/5amvG/

I Hope this is what you are looking for

**CSS:**

```
#popup{
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
}
#popup:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="popup">
    Sell yourself and say what makes you,you !
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help you:

**Pure CSS speech bubbles**:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/